# Dot notation for methods

Tags: dart

I would like to know if in Dart you can define groups of methods within a class and use dot notation. Example:

```
this.GroupOfMethods1.method1 ()

this.GroupOfMethods1.method2 ()

this.GroupOfMethods1.method3 ()



this.GroupOfMethods2.method1 ()

this.GroupOfMethods2.method2 ()

this.GroupOfMethods2.method3 ()
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of that? I'm not sure what you're after, but I'm pretty sure there is nothing like that in Dart.

Comment: For example, for the structural element class there is the same verification (the same method) that develops differently depending on the standard that is applied. In this way "resistance to compression" in a standard will have different equations with respect to "compression resistance" in another standard ... How could I get out of this elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

You could kind of hack that together, if you really had to.

```
void main() {
  SomeClass(); // prints "method1"
}

class SomeClass {
  final group1 = GroupOfMethods1();
  SomeClass() {
    this.group1.method1();
  }
}

class GroupOfMethods1 {
  final method1 = () => print('method1');
}
```

If you really need a dynamic bunch of functions with names, you could keep them in a map.

```
class SomeClass2 {
  final group1 = <String, void Function()>{};
  SomeClass2() {
    group1['method1'] = () => print('method1');
    group1['method1']();
  }
}
```

But this is *very* unlikely to be what you should be doing.